# How can I migrate my Redmine deployment from MySQL 5 to PostgeSQL 8.2?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, migration, redmine

I have full access to both databases, but clearly a MySQL dump file isn't going to import cleanly into Postgres.  Are there any good step-by-steps for migrating from MySQL to Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few MySQL -> PostgreSQL migration resources linked from the [PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Converting_from_other_Databases_to_PostgreSQL#MySQL). I've never tried migration with Redmine though.

PostgreSQL 8.2 is quite old now, is it provided by a hosting provider, or can you use a more recent version?

Answer (score 0):

I've used [SQL::Translator](http://search.cpan.org/dist/SQL-Translator/) to do mysql to postgres conversions in the past. Worked pretty well for me.